# Long polling and laravel

Tags: php, laravel, comet, long-polling

I was thinking of using long-polling for my laravel app like so:

- Client starts request
- Server checks if there is anything new in db, if there is , respond with that
- Else , sleep for 1 second, and repeat 2.
- Do 2&3 for 40 seconds, and finally die if there has been nothing new for that duration.

When I asked about this, some people said:

> @harvey_slash Sleeping inside Controller method sounds like a
>   extremely bad idea, and will not work the way you want. Like jimmck
>   said, even if you manage to get that work, you are still wasting lots
>   of resources for nothing.

and also

> @harvey_slash Note that PHP's "new process per request"-paradigm* does
>   not make it very suitable for long-polling. In enviroments like
>   Node.js long-polling is more suitable as you are not generating new
>   processes for each request.
>
> What I would question here is why do you need long-polling at all? Can
>   you elaborate why websockets or something else (like simply polling
>   once every couple seconds) would not work?
>
> - with PHP-FPM this may not apply, I don't know the details...

My question is, is it really that bad to do what I am planning to do?
I thought Facebook does nearly the same thing with the same technologies(Php,long poll)

If it is such a bad idea, what other options do I have except pusher.

Comment: Websockets? As a commenter said: "Can you elaborate why websockets or something else (like simply polling once every couple seconds) would not work?".

Comment: Is it possible to integrate web sockets with laravel ?

Comment: Websockets can be integrated nearly everywhere and it is quite simple. Look at [socket.oi](http://socket.io/). I have used it myself and was amazed how few lines of code are needed to set it up.

Comment: @harvey_slash Yes. You may want to check out this laracasts series: https://laracasts.com/series/real-time-laravel-with-socket-io/episodes/1 but I'm sure if you google web sockets & laravel you will get some tuts on how to get started

Comment: I took a look at ratchet and laravel. Could you tell me if there a tutorial on how to set them both using JUST laravel and ratchet ?